# How to add a table at a fixed point after heading pages with VB and itextsharp

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

I have the following code which creates two header tables, and a table to follow.
I can't insert the table below immediately after the header.
They both start at the top of the page,
The second table should start immediately after the gray header grid.
Everything must be repeated on each page

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Public Doc As Document
    Public wri As PdfWriter

    Public fntNormal12 As iTextSharp.text.Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)
    Public TableGrid As PdfPTable '= New PdfPTable(5)
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Doc = New Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 20, 20)

        Dim ev As _events = New _events() ' ora

        wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, New FileStream("simple2.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        ' evento per nuova pagina

        wri.PageEvent = ev  ' ora

        Doc.Open()

        TableGrid = New PdfPTable(5) ' diventata pubblica

        TableGrid.WidthPercentage = 100 ' Table size is set to 100% of the page
        TableGrid.HorizontalAlignment = 0 '0=left, 1=centre , 2 = right
        TableGrid.SpacingAfter = 10   ' mette uno spazio di 10 ,  dopo

        Dim TableGridWidths(4) As Single
        TableGridWidths(0) = 150 ' se li metto tutti e 3 uguali è come se faccio il 33%
        TableGridWidths(1) = 200
        TableGridWidths(2) = 500
        TableGridWidths(3) = 50
        TableGridWidths(4) = 100

        TableGrid.SetWidths(TableGridWidths) ' Set the column widths on table creation. Unlike HTML cells cannot be sized.

        Try
            For i = 0 To 100

                '2° riga verde
                Dim GrillCell1 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Pos." & i, fntNormal12))
                'CellOne.Rotation = -90 ' inclina il testo
                GrillCell1.HorizontalAlignment = 1 '0=left, 1=centre , 2 = right
                TableGrid.AddCell(GrillCell1)

                Dim GrillCell2 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("PS" & i, fntNormal12))
                'CellTwo.Border = 0
                GrillCell2.HorizontalAlignment = 1 '0=left, 1=centre , 2 = right
                TableGrid.AddCell(GrillCell2)

                Dim GrillCell3 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("DDDDDDDDDDDD" & i, fntNormal12))
                GrillCell3.HorizontalAlignment = 1 '0=left, 1=centre , 2 = right
                TableGrid.AddCell(GrillCell3)

                Dim GrillCell4 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(i, fntNormal12))
                GrillCell4.HorizontalAlignment = 1 '0=left, 1=centre , 2 = right
                TableGrid.AddCell(GrillCell4)

                Dim GrillCell5 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(i, fntNormal12))
                GrillCell5.HorizontalAlignment = 1 '0=left, 1=centre , 2 = right
                TableGrid.AddCell(GrillCell5)

            Next i

            Doc.Add(TableGrid)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)

            Doc.Close()

        End Try

        Doc.Close()

        Process.Start("simple2.pdf")

    End Sub

End Class


Class _events
    Inherits PdfPageEventHelper

    Public Vvv = "VVV11111"
    Public Ppp = "PPP 11111"
    Public Vv = "VV 11111"
    Public Ggg = "GGG 11111"
    Public Pppp = "3333"
    Public Ttt = "tttttttttt"
    Public myTable As PdfPTable
    Public myTableBC As PdfPTable
    Public TableGridInt As PdfPTable '= New PdfPTable(5)

    Public Logo = "tttttttttt"
    'Public logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Application.StartupPath & "\" & "MioLogo.jpg")
    ' settaggio intestazione
    Public fntBOLD18 As iTextSharp.text.Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 18, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)
    ' altro settaggio verde
    Public fntBOLD12 As iTextSharp.text.Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)
    Public fntBOLD8 As iTextSharp.text.Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)

    ' altro settaggio verde
    Public fntNormal18 As iTextSharp.text.Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 18, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)
    Public fntNormal12 As iTextSharp.text.Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)
    Public fntNormal8 As iTextSharp.text.Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)

    Public Overrides Sub OnEndPage(ByVal writer As PdfWriter, ByVal document As Document)

        myTable = New PdfPTable(4)

        myTable.WidthPercentage = 100 ' Table size is set to 100% of the page
        myTable.HorizontalAlignment = 0 '0=left, 1=centre , 2 = right
        myTable.SpacingAfter = 10   ' mette uno spazio di 10 ,  dopo

        Dim sglTblHdWidths(3) As Single
        sglTblHdWidths(0) = 150 ' se li metto tutti e 3 uguali è come se faccio il 33%
        sglTblHdWidths(1) = 580
        sglTblHdWidths(2) = 140
        sglTblHdWidths(3) = 130

        myTable.SetWidths(sglTblHdWidths) ' Set the column widths on table creation. Unlike HTML cells cannot be sized.

        myTable.AddCell(logo)

        Dim CellTwoHdr As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Mia Stampa", fntBOLD18)) ' font intestazione rosso
        CellTwoHdr.HorizontalAlignment = 1
        myTable.AddCell(CellTwoHdr)

        Dim CellTreeHdr As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(("38 38     "), fntBOLD12)) ' font intestazione rosso
        myTable.AddCell(CellTreeHdr)

        Dim Cell4Hdr As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(("Mio canale: " & " 34"), fntNormal8)) ' font intestazione rosso
        Cell4Hdr.HorizontalAlignment = 2
        Cell4Hdr.VerticalAlignment = 2 ' non funziona
        myTable.AddCell(Cell4Hdr)


        '2° riga verde
        Dim CellOne As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("PROVA", fntNormal12))
        'CellOne.Rotation = -90 ' inclina il testo
        myTable.AddCell(CellOne)

        Dim CellTwo As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("", fntNormal8))
        'CellTwo.Border = 0
        myTable.AddCell(CellTwo)

        Dim CellTree As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(Now, fntNormal8))
        myTable.AddCell(CellTree)

        Dim Cell4 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("p  di  p ", fntNormal8))
        Cell4.HorizontalAlignment = 2
        myTable.AddCell(Cell4)

        document.Add(myTable)

        TableGridInt = New PdfPTable(5) ' diventata pubblica

        TableGridInt.WidthPercentage = 100 ' Table size is set to 100% of the page
        TableGridInt.HorizontalAlignment = 0 '0=left, 1=centre , 2 = right
        TableGridInt.SpacingAfter = 10   ' mette uno spazio di 10 ,  dopo

        Dim TableGridWidths(4) As Single
        TableGridWidths(0) = 150 ' se li metto tutti e 3 uguali è come se faccio il 33%
        TableGridWidths(1) = 200
        TableGridWidths(2) = 500
        TableGridWidths(3) = 50
        TableGridWidths(4) = 100

        TableGridInt.SetWidths(TableGridWidths) ' Set the column widths on table creation. Unlike HTML cells cannot be sized.

        '2° riga verde
        Dim IntCol1 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Point1", fntBOLD8))
        'CellOne.Rotation = -90 ' inclina il testo
        IntCol1.HorizontalAlignment = 1 '0=left, 1=centre , 2 = right
        IntCol1.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY
        TableGridInt.AddCell(IntCol1)

        Dim IntCol2 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Pt2", fntBOLD8))
        'CellTwo.Border = 0
        IntCol2.HorizontalAlignment = 1 '0=left, 1=centre , 2 = right
        IntCol2.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY
        TableGridInt.AddCell(IntCol2)

        Dim IntCol3 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Des", fntBOLD8))
        IntCol3.HorizontalAlignment = 1 '0=left, 1=centre , 2 = right
        IntCol3.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY
        TableGridInt.AddCell(IntCol3)

        Dim IntCol4 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Q.", fntBOLD8))
        IntCol4.HorizontalAlignment = 1 '0=left, 1=centre , 2 = right
        IntCol4.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY
        TableGridInt.AddCell(IntCol4)

        Dim IntCol5 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Point5", fntBOLD8))
        IntCol5.HorizontalAlignment = 1 '0=left, 1=centre , 2 = right
        IntCol5.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY
        TableGridInt.AddCell(IntCol5)

        document.Add(TableGridInt)

    End Sub
```

I have already tried using the WriteSelectedRows method, but the result is that it never goes into the OnEndPage event and therefore at most I have about 28 or 30 table rows and not the others.

What could be the problem then?

Comment: You add content to the `OnEndPage` parameter `document`. You are not expected to do that; after all you are in `OnEndPage` because the page is getting finalized because it is full. If you add content in `OnEndPage`, you are expected to do so by retrieving the `DirectContent` from the `writer` argument and adding the content to that direct content manually (in case of tables using the `PdfPTable` method `WriteSelectedRows`. And to make sure that there is some free space, you should choose the margins in your `Document` constructor so that the main body does not overlap the header area.

Comment: I have already tried using the WriteSelectedRows method, but the result is that it never goes into the OnEndPage event and therefore at most I have about 28 or 30 table rows and not the others.

What could be the problem then?

Comment: *"I have already tried using the WriteSelectedRows method, but the result is that it never goes into the OnEndPage event and therefore at most I have about 28 or 30 table rows and not the others. What could be the problem then?"* - that makes no sense, those two things are not related (unless the code has syntax errors and VB reacts weirdly to it instead of simply refusing to run, or something equally funny).